# Creating python c module independent of python version?

Tags: python, module, tcl

In Tcl, there is a concept of stubs, where you can have a C extension that works with any compatible version of Tcl.  Is there a comparable concept for Python?

I'd like to distribute a binary module that would run on Ubuntu 8.04 (python 2.5), Ubuntu 10.04 (python 2.6), and Centos 5 (python 2.4).  I'd like to only have to distribute a 32 bit and a 64 bit version for Linux that would be compatible with all 3.  I'd redistribute libstdc++ and compile for glib 2.7 which is forward compatible with glib 2.11.

Comment: You might want to explain why you don't want to distribute as source (and so avoid this problem).

Comment: Possibly he's aiming to have his module independant on a compiler being installed.

Comment: I'd like to be able to distribute an application which uses the default python versions on the system.  I don't want to have to worry that the application will break if the python version if updated.  On Windows I can ask customers to download a specific version from python.org.  On Mac OS X, python is already installed.  On Linux I am at the mercy of each distribution having a different python version.

Comment: I removed the `stubs` tag, as it's previously been used just for stubs for unit testing. Alas.

Comment: You people answering this don't have a clue. Just answer his question rather than question his approach. Version independent extension libs for Python - is it so difficult to understand why this is desirable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you distribute your module as source, it can be compiled as necessary.

This problem occurs a lot with Windows, for which modules are normally distributed as binaries. [PEP 384](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0384/) proposes a solution (a limited interface which is guaranteed to exist for all Python 3 versions) and is implemented in Python 3.2. Until then, you're stuck.

Comment: Thank you.  Reading their description sounds a lot like the Tcl stubs approach.